# How to make paging with parallaxHeader effect SAME like twitter?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, parallax

I want to make PAGING and parallaxHeader same like twitter here.
I add one screenshot that i design.

Here what actually happen is i Use a `UITableviewcontroler` with three `section` and in section add `UICollectionview` when i scroll up and third section is come then i stop the `TABLE` scroll and enable scroll of `UIcollectionview` but is not working as i want

A scroll is working but not smooth as like Twitter.

[image]

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let sectionHeaderFrame = self.tableView.convert(self.viewTabMain.frame, to: appDelegate.window)

    let activeScrollView: UIScrollView!

    if scrollView == self.clvBuying || scrollView == self.clvSelling || scrollView == self.clvShared || scrollView == self.ClvSellList  {

        activeScrollView = scrollView
        debugPrint(activeScrollView.contentOffset.y)
        if activeScrollView.contentOffset.y > 0.2 {

            activeScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
        else {

            activeScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }



    }
    else if scrollView == self.tableView {

        let offsetY: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        self.clvBuying.setContentOffset(offsetY, animated: false)
        self.clvSelling.setContentOffset(offsetY, animated: false)
        self.clvShared.setContentOffset(offsetY, animated: false)
        self.ClvSellList.setContentOffset(offsetY, animated: false)

       debugPrint("TBL \(sectionHeaderFrame.origin.y)")
        if sectionHeaderFrame.origin.y <= 43 {

            self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
            self.clvBuying.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.clvSelling.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.clvShared.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.ClvSellList.isScrollEnabled = true

        } else {

                 self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

                self.clvBuying.isScrollEnabled = false
                self.clvSelling.isScrollEnabled = false
                self.clvShared.isScrollEnabled = false
                self.ClvSellList.isScrollEnabled = false
         }
    }

}
```